# WordPress: add check-boxes to custom taxonomy add/edit form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, checkbox, custom-taxonomy

I need to add a list of check-boxes to custom taxonomy add/edit form.
I have this code for adding a text field for custom taxonomy form in my plugin and it works fine:

```
    <?php
    function taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {
        $t_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); 
    ?>

        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Term:' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

    function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
            $t_id = $term_id;
            $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
            $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
                if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                    $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
                }
            }
            update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
        }
    }  
    add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
    add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

How I can add a list of check-boxes in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a problem with the saving not checked check-box input.
I have fixed it with input type="hidden" with the same value of "name" attribute, as in check-box input.

```
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Color:' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" value="0" name="term_meta[pa_color_attr]">
            <input type="checkbox" <?php echo (!empty($term_meta['pa_color_attr']) ? ' checked="checked" ' : 'test'); ?> value="1" name="term_meta[pa_color_attr]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the name of the hook.

```
 add_action( 'edited_custom_tax', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What values of attributes should I add to the check-box input tag (name, value)?

How can I save checked field? How to display checked boxes on edit page?